# How to rewrite this js class without decorators

Tags: javascript, decorator, mobx, mobx-persist

I want to use mobx without using decorators. Usually I use `decorate` from mobx package but in this particular case, I could not find a way to make it work.

Original code :

```
import { observable } from 'mobx'
import { create, persist } from 'mobx-persist'

class Order {
  @persist('object')
  @observable
  currentOrder = null
}
```

What I tried :

```
import { observable, decorate } from 'mobx'
import { create, persist } from 'mobx-persist'
import { compose } from 'recompose'

class Order {
  currentOrder = null
}

decorate(Order, {
    currentOrder: compose(persist('object'), observable),
})
```

The error comes from `persist` telling serializr decorator is not used properly.
Any idea why this is different from above and does not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Property Decorators requires a very specific composition implementation.

Solution Demo:
[image: Edit MobX Decorators Composer]

#### Full Answer

Property Decorators are basically a function of the form:
`(target, prop, descriptor) => modifiedDescriptor`

So, in order to compose two Property Decorators you need to pass the **1st decorator**'s result as a third argument of the **2nd decorator** (along with `target` and `prop`).

[`Recompose.compose`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#compose) (same as [`lodash.flowRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flowRight)) applies functions from right to left and passing the result as a **single** argument to the next function.

Thus, you can't use `Recompose.compose` for composing decorators, but you can easily create a composer for decorators:

```js
/* compose.js */

export default (...decorators) => (target, key, descriptor) =>
  decorators.reduce(
    (accDescriptor, decorator) => decorator(target, key, accDescriptor),
    descriptor
  );
```

Then we use it in order to compose `observable` and `persist("object")`.

```js
/* Order.js */

import { observable, decorate, action } from "mobx";
import { persist } from "mobx-persist";
import compose from "./compose";

class Order {
  currentOrder = null;
}

export default decorate(Order, {
  currentOrder: compose(
    observable,
    persist("object")
  )
});
```

### [21/8/18] Update for MobX `>=4.3.2` & `>=5.0.4`:

I opened PRs (which have been merged) for [MobX5](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/pull/1652) & [MobX4](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/pull/1691) in order to support multiple decorators OOB within the `decorate` utility function.
So, this is available in MobX `>=4.3.2` & `>= 5.0.4`:

```js
import { decorate, observable } from 'mobx'
import { serializable, primitive } from 'serializr'
import persist from 'mobx-persist';

class Todo {
    id = Math.random();
    title = "";
    finished = false;
}
decorate(Todo, {
    title: [serializable(primitive), persist('object'), observable],
    finished: observable
})
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution is to have

```js
class Stuff {
   title = ''
   object = {
      key: value
   }
}

decorate(Todo, {
    title: [persist, observable],
    object: [persist('object'),observable]
})
```

No need to install the serializr package. The above functionality is built into mobx persist.